# How can I get an RSS link to auto open in iTunes/WinAmp/etc

Tags: rss, itunes, podcast

I have user generated podcasts, each with their own RSS feed. Is there a way to automatically open iTunes when the link to the RSS feed is clicked?

I've seen this happen before, but the podcast had always been submitted to Apple and approved. This is not practical for hundreds of user-generated podcasts.

I tried linking like `itunes://http://site.com/blah` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

There are two protocols, `pcast://` and `itpc://` (the second may stand for "iTunes PC"). Feedburner uses the first of those, so that is what I'm going to use.

**Update:** Firefox doesn't support `pcast` (WTF Mozilla?). `itpc` works in all browsers I tested.

Comment: Now neither browser supports pcast.

Comment: Unfortunately even Mac os doesn't support itpc:// anymore. :(